# Migrando dato BLOB de MySQLi a PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Poseo el siguiente codigo funcional en MySQLi:

```
$sql = "SELECT contenido FROM contenido WHERE seccion = '$s' " ;
$resultado = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or mysqli_error($db);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);
```

pero estoy migrando a PDO intente con este codigo pero no da resultados esperados

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT contenido FROM contenido WHERE seccion = '$s' ") ;
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

El dato contenido se almacena en MySQL como un longblob no he logrado hacerlo funcionar he probado lo siguiente sin exito:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT contenido FROM contenido WHERE seccion = 'index' ") ;
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->bindColumn(1, $data, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
 $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND);
 echo $data;
```

Comment: ¿Qué muestra un `var_dump($data);`?

Comment: Hola, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: puedes presentar tu esquema usando este sitio http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 0):

Yo los suelo castear a tipo varchar con utf8 para que me respete caracteres especiales, tildes, etc...
Básicamente lo hago así:

> cast(CONTENIDO as varchar(8191) character set utf8) AS CONTENIDO

En tu ejemplo, quedaría así:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT cast(contenido as varchar(8191) character set utf8) AS contenido FROM contenido WHERE seccion = 'index' ");
```

Prueba así a ver si te funciona.
Suerte.

Comment: Saludos me da error: Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'varchar(8191) character set utf8) AS contenido y en la web Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'varchar(8191) character set utf8) AS contenido FROM contenido WHERE seccion

Comment: Puede que sea por el tipo de base de datos o tratarse de longblob. Al menos cuando casteo tipo blob desde firebird funciona bien con esa fórmula. Tal vez en MySql sea algo diferente, pero por ahí deben andar los tiros.

Comment: por eso no se responden preguntas a las que le faltan datos